# How to Sorting a json obj based on a value with php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, json

I have a json object something like this:

```
{"528":5,"527":1,"526":2,"524":6}
```

what I need is:

```
{"527":1,"526":2,"528":5,"524":6}
```

Comment: So, how would you like to achieve this?

Comment: That isn't an array. It's an object. Objects properties have no order. The only ordered thing in [JSON](http://json.org) is an array, which is written with the `[` and `]` characters. ("Array" not like "associative array" in PHP parlance that's actually a dictionary or map, but in the sense of an ordered series of items.)

Comment: This isn't a Array, this is a Object

Comment: then how to sort that object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fiddle Example](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/2ux-3mf)

```
<?php
   $json='{"528":5,"527":1,"526":2,"524":6}';
   var_dump($json);
   $arr=json_decode($json,true);
   echo "<pre />";
   print_r($arr);
   asort($arr);
   print_r($arr);
   $json=json_encode($arr);
   var_dump($json);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do like this...

```
 <?php
    $arr = json_decode('{"528":5,"527":1,"526":2,"524":6}',true); //<--- converting the object to an array , by passing second arg true
    asort($arr);// sorting the array in ascending ....
    $arr = json_encode($arr); //encoding back !
    echo $arr;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
{"527":1,"526":2,"528":5,"524":6}
```

Comment: Using the second argument of `json_decode()` is definitely the way to go here. +1 (if you ask me I would use `true` instead of `1`. While it does the same in that example I think it is more readable..

Comment: @hek2mgl, Thanks for the note. Edited as per your comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do:

1. parse json to jsObject (with jquery etc)
2. get all Attributes of the object (`for(var propertyName in myObject)`)
3. Iterate over them to get that one with the smallest Value and write it in a array
4. Do this until all Attributes are in the array.